# how to run a test case multiple times in watir

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, iteration, watir

I have a test script created and I have a scenario where I have to run it for 3000 time. Can any one please write me a code to do this.

My Test Script Name is 'reg.rb'

and the test case name inside that file to un is 'test_case1 = @html.newTestName('TC1 - Registration through Net')'

Comment: Please, make it more clear. Do you need just to run the `reg.rb` 3000 times?

Comment: Yes... that is correct... in reg.rb file I have one test case and I want to run it 3000 times. It is fine if i run reg.rb file 3000 times also. Just need to know how to run it 3000 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ruby -e X" is a quick and dirty way to execute an entire file X amount of times, but for just the lines you need X.times do is the proper Ruby way.

```
testtest_case1 = @html.newTestName('TC1 - Create')
ie.link(:href, /Login.jsp/).click
ie.link(:href, /loginUser.jsp/).click
ie.textField(:name, "textlogin").set login
ie.textField(:name, "textpassword").set password
ie.button(:src, /btn_login.gif/).click

# Need to run below steps 3000 times

3000.times do
    ie.frame.textField(:name, "total").set amount
    ie.frame.button(:src, /go.gif/).click
    sleep(5)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the following in terminal `ruby -e "3000.times { load('reg.rb') }"`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have not tried this yet but will try it now. mean while can I know if I want to execute only a perticular step or some steps in the test case 3000 time, then how to do it.. Can you please give me an example with the code...

Comment: I can if you give me the code of your test. By the way, care to +1 answer and accept if it's that helpful.

Comment: This is the code in the 

testtest_case1 = @html.newTestName('TC1 - Create')


       ie.link(:href, /Login.jsp/).click

       ie.link(:href, /loginUser.jsp/).click
       ie.textField(:name, "textlogin").set login
       ie.textField(:name, "textpassword").set password
       ie.button(:src, /btn_login.gif/).click

Need to run below steps 3000 times

ie.frame.textField(:name, "total").set amount
        ie.frame.button(:src, /go.gif/).click
        sleep(5)

Comment: The above mentioned solution is not working. It is giving away this error

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/element.rb:78:in `asse
rt_exists': Unable to locate element, using :href, /Login.jsp/ (Watir::Excep
tion::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: That's not the solution issue. First, how do you open the page which you interact with, what's `@html` instance of, where do you initialize `ie`? Second, post code to pastebin or gist so it's more readable.

Comment: Your script does not handle errors.  You're trying to assert that a link with the href of /Login.jsp/ exists, but it doesn't, so the script is exiting.  You could be on the wrong page.  The href may be different/has changed.  The site could be down.  This doesn't have to do with whether or not it's going to do that 3000 times.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The solution given by Adam is what i was exactly looking at. Thank you for the help